# PHP email processor not working

Tags: php, forms, email

I have some code that is a basic email form. It's not working. I know my form works because it's a prettified version of a form I made for someone else..

It could be that it's late and I overlooked something.

```
<?php
    $subject = 'Contact Form ';
    $subject .= $_POST['subject'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $comments = strip_tags($_POST['comments']);
    $url    = $_POST['url'];
    $to = 'someemail@email.com';
    $headers = "From: ".$name." <".$email.">\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $comments, $headers);
?>
```

Of course, after I get it working I'm, going to put in some anti-spam measures. I've tried even tried to output the content of the variables. It seems somehow related to $_POST.

Edit: Apparently my host uses php4 by default and I used "AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php" in .htaccess to force php5, and it fixed all my problems. :)

Comment: Can you explain `It's not working`?

Comment: This code seems to be okay, there is no problem.

Comment: Have you checked your SMTP settings?

Comment: Yep, it seems to be working, if you don't care about security.

Comment: Found a solution and updated my original question with it so other people would see the solution. It's hard to think I'm going to bed. I'll make security related edits tomorrow like anti-spam measures and header injection protection.

Answer (score 0):

Code seems to be fine. Try to debug the mail result:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$result = mail($to, $subject, $comments, $headers);
var_dump($result);
```

Guess your smtp settings are wrong or not configured at all.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your php.ini 
http://www.php.net//manual/en/mail.configuration.php

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mail.asp

I think, mail function is disabled in your server.

Comment: That's a very nice *comment* :)